# How to embed twitter timeline in a horizontal slider

Tags: twitter

What I'm trying to do is displaying my twitter timeline feeds in a website dynamically in a slider/carousel.

without copying and pasting every last tweet.
something looks like the testimonials section on this page
https://slack.com/pricing